# Centering Page Links on Nav Menu

Tags: html, css, nav

I would like a full-width navigation menu with the remainder of the page having a width of 960px.

The links on the navigation menu need to be centered above the 960px width body.

The below code is aligning the nav menu to the left hand side. What do I need to include to have the nav links centered?

HTML

```
<div class="nav">
   <ul>
      <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Our Products</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">FAQs</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="main">
      <p>ABC ABC ABC</p>
      <p>ABC ABC ABC</p>
      <p>ABC ABC ABC</p>
      <p>ABC ABC ABC</p>
      <p>ABC ABC ABC</p>
      <p>ABC ABC ABC</p>
      <p>ABC ABC ABC</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper {
    background-color: red;
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.nav {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 1em 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}

.nav li {
    float: left;
}

.nav li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 8px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #069;
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.nav li:first-child a {
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.nav li a:hover {
    color: #c00;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Seriously!!..I second that

Comment: Edited to include HTML. Sorry missed it out on initial post.

Comment: If I got you right you want to center your navigation above a 960px wide content area? If so, try @tokyodrift's idea or take a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Moonbird_IT/7X3Lb/

Comment: Thanks. Yes that is correct. I have given tokyodrift's idea a go and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.nav ul {
    list-style: none; 
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0; 
    text-align: center;
}

.nav li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should not "float" the links if you want them to appear in the center.. instead, try using "display:inline-block" for the nav links items (nav li) and add "text-align:center" to the list itself (nav ul)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
.nav { text-align: center; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Link: http://jsfiddle.net/CdkXG/2/

CSS:

```
.wrapper { 
   clear: both;
}
```